# Flow Line of this Vector Field

Tags: vector-fields

I need to find the flow line of the field $F(x,y,z) = e^y\hat i + x\hat j + xy^2z\hat k$ that passes through the point (2,1,1). The answer is supposed to be in the form $x = f(y), y = y, z = g(y)$. I was wondering if someone could check if my answer was correct, I got $x = \sqrt{2(e^y + 2 - e)}$ and $z = e^\left(1/3\left(y^3 - 1\right)\right)$

Comment: How do you define *flow line*?

Comment: Based on my notes, it's setting dx/F1(x,y,z) = dy/F2(x,y,z) = dz/F3(x,y,z), then solving using separable equations. The 3 equations are supposed to be the flowline

Comment: OK, that would seem to be the line whose velocity follows the field.